# $.get() not working in IE8 or IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get

*Note: I have only tried in IE8 and IE7 (via IE8 developer tools) as these are the only versions available to me.*

I am using an ajax search plugin for Wordpress, the plugin can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-ajax-search/

It is working fantastically in firefox, however IE shows signs of making an ajax request and then failling. I have narrowed this down to IE recieving no results from the `$.get()` function by using `alert(ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.total_results);` which always alerts `0` even when other browsers get a number of results. Here is the section of the plugin which handles the ajax request:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
        ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results = $('.hentry', data);

        // Remove extra elements if necessary
        ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.total_results = ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results.length;
        alert(ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.total_results);
        if ( ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results.length > ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.options.results_to_display )
        {
            ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results = ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results.slice( 0, ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.options.results_to_display );
        }

        if ( ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.results.length < 1 )
            ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.hide_results();

        ThreeWP_Ajax_Search.do_callback(callback);
    });
```

*Note: `url` is the standard Wordpress search url and is handled by the wordpress search engine. I have a few search plugins but they are all performed on the server-side.*

I have also tried replacing `$.get()` to `$.ajax()` and setting `cache: false` however that had no effect whatsoever.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

A live example can be found at: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/ (Searching for 'care' returns a number of results)

Comment: what does the ThreeWP_Ajax_Search object do?

Comment: @MrFoh Returns search results as you type into a searchbox, (queries the wordpress search page for your term and returns the results).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is some conditional JS loaded when the browser is IE7 or IE8. The file is called "selectivizr-mis.js" and it is returning a 404 error when loaded.

Perhaps the IE7 and IE8 functionality of the site rely on something within this file in order to work correctly?

In either case that file should probably be loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me the URL it is attempting to access it by? (Can't seem to get net connections on my IE). However selectivizr just provides some CSS support for legacy browsers. Won't affect ajax calls.

Comment: visited your site again tonight. I saw this error: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Fri, 27 Apr 2012 05:59:14 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/library/js/corners.js?ver=1.0.0

Comment: Thanks its unrelated I was just in the middle of trying something out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the lack oF CORS support in IE7/IE8. Perhaps this might help?

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: It is performing the requests on the same domain. Is this also affected as the article refers to ajax requests across different domains?

Comment: @GeorgeReith yeah if origin domain is test.com and the other domain is a.test.com, this constitutes a cross domain request

Comment: @MrFoh I am not using subdomains though, the request makes a request on the same domain.